Laravel: Scheduled command not getting executed in development environment
I am working on a Laravel project and have created a command with signature 'process:pending-reports'.
When I run this using: php artisan process:pending-reports, it does the needful i.e. the script gets executed.
I have now added this to the schedule() method inside app/Console/Kernel.php file as so:
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('process:pending-reports')->everyFifteenMinutes();
    }

When I check the details using:
php artisan schedule:list
I again get the expected output like:
 */15 * * * *  php artisan process:pending-reports ................................................................................................... Next Due: 7 minutes from now 

However, once the time for command execution passes, it does not actually run the command.
What am I missing?

The Laravel Scheduler must be added to the crontab:
you can edit it using the command:

crontab -e

then add a line like this:
* * * * * cd /path/to/your/project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Here is the reference

On windows there's an equivalent way to do this using the task scheduler

Command php artisan schedule:list just listing your scheduled task, not running the task.
For running scheduled task on local development, you can use command php artisan schedule:work. This command will run in the foreground and invoke the scheduler every minute until you terminate the command.
source:
Laravel Task Scheduling
